# How to extract src value from image tag using JMeter Css extractor

Tags: jmeter

How to extract src value from image tag using JMeter Css extractor.

For example

<img src="tmp/anil_psl.png" / >

Need to extract src value  ie. tmp/anil_psl.png

Thanks

Comment: `tmp/anil_psl.png` is dynamic and you want to extract it? you have only one `img`? if not, how will you find the relevant img?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put `img` as the "Selector"
2. Put `src` as the "Attribute"

[image]

You may also be interested in [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) articles

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, You Rock :)